# Twice continuously differentiable wavelets with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, wavelets

Do there exists wavelets such that both mother wavelet and the scaling function have compact support and they are both twice continuously differentiable?

Comment: You might want to define these terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I believe that [Daubechies Wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daubechies_wavelet) of high orders satisfy this.

Daubechies Wavelets have a compact support (that's why they were invented), and the higher the order, the higher the regularity.

[This doc](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~brani/isyebayes/bank/handout20.pdf) relates the order of the Daubechies Wavelets (and scaling functions) with their [Holder exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition). It seems that at order 7, both wavelets and scaling functions are of holder exponent $\geq 2$, which  implies that they're both twice continuously differentiable.